# Cannot create a driver with webdriver manager for Brave/Firefox and Selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I copy/paste webdriver manager code example for using Brave as a driver from officially documentation -> https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

After running the code I am AttributeError:

[image]

For Firefox I am getting:
[image]

I am using Python 3.11 and everything running inside of venv.

Anyone else had same issues and has steps to fix them?

Thank you!

I tried to use webdriver manager with Selenium 4.
I cannot create driver for Brave and Firefox browser.